# Symfony array as Form Collection

Tags: php, symfony

I have been stuck with a problem in Symfony for days, and can't find anything on google.

I have two tables.

Account:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Account:
type: entity
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
oneToMany:
    towns:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Town
        mappedBy: owner
        cascade: ['persist']
```

Town:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Town:
type: entity
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
manyToOne:
    owner:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Account
        inversedBy: towns
```

And I have an array with names:

```
$names = ['New York','Berlin'];
```

I want a form in which the user can check a name from the array (Check boxes). When the user checks 'New York' and submits the form, I want a new entity `Town` with 'New York' in the `name` field. If the user unchecks 'New York', I want the entity removed.

So far I tried it with `EntityType`, `CollectionType`, and `ChoiceType`. The Best I can get is with ChoiceType.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('towns', ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'choices' =>
                    [
                        new Town('New York'),
                        new Town('Berlin'),
                    ],
                'choice_label' => function (Town $town, $key, $index) {
                    return $town->getName();
                },
                'choice_value' => function (Town $town) {
                    return $town->getName();
                },
                'expanded' => TRUE,
                'multiple' => TRUE,
                'required' => FALSE,
            ]
        );
}
```

But it will add a new entity every time the user submits the form for any town that is checked and it does not remove the non checked one...

Comment: Sorry but what is your question? You say "_I want a new entity "Town" with 'New York' in the name field. If the user unchecks 'New York' I want the entity removed_" and then you say "_But it will add a new entity every time the user submits the form and any town is checked and it does remove the non checked one_". It sounds like it does exactly what you want...

Comment: It's strange to instantiate entities in your form builder though.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. It does not remove. And it should not generate a new entity if an entity with the same name already exists.

Comment: Where does the array of towns names come from and do you really have to use it? It's in the title of your question but you don't use it in your form builder example.

Comment: The array is in the 'choices' Field. I create it from two queries.

Comment: In the `choices` option of your example it's not an array of names as described above ( `$names = ['New York', 'Berlin'];` ). If my answer below doesn't help, please could you add to your question the code with these two queries and the reason why you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array, store the towns in the database.
Then set the `towns` field type to `EntityType`.

```
->add(
    'towns',
    EntityType::class,
    [
        'class' => Town::class,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'required' => false,
    ]
)
```

Add this method to your Town class to display the name automatically everywhere it has to be converted to string:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

---

If the idea with the array was to filter the choices displayed to choose towns, you could use it in the `query_builder` option:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $names = ['New York', 'Berlin']; // Or pass it from the controller in $options

    $builder
        ->add('towns',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Town::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($names) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('town')
                        ->where('town.name IN (:names)')
                        ->setParameter('names', $names);
                },
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );
}
```